# ffmpeg convert white color to alpha

Tags: ffmpeg, transparency, alpha, palette

Hello i took a picture with my camera :a drawing of a square frame on a white paper; i'm trying to convert the white to transparent and keep the black color frame.

So i started making 1 palette with only 2 colors to make the colors uniform and 1 palette to add the transparency

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=color=white:100x100" -f lavfi -i "color=color=black:100x100" -filter_complex "[0][1]hstack" -frames:v 1 blackwhite.png`
ffmpeg -i blackwhite.png -filter_complex "[0]split[a][b];[a]palettegen[pal1];[b]palettegen=reserve_transparent=on:transparency_color=white[pal2]" -map [pal1] palette1.png -map [pal2] palette2.png
```

then i mapped the image png of the frame to convert the white to transparent and overlayed the result to a red background

```
ffmpeg -i image.png -i palette1.png -i palette2.png -i background.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]paletteuse=dither=bayer[a],[a]split[a1][a2];[a1][2:v]paletteuse=alpha_threshold=128[c];[3:v][c]overlay[d]" -map [a2] -c:v png out.png -map [d] -c:v png out1.png
```

the png mapped to the first palette (as a test) comes as it should be, pure black and white,the second comes with no transparency at all and covers the background
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

ok i figured out a way with the alpha-merge filter, there's no need for the second palette that allows transparent.

so i started simply

```
ffmpeg -i image.png -i palette.png -filter_complex "paletteuse=dither=bayer" image2colors.png
ffmpeg -i background.png -i image2colors.png -filter_complex "alphamerge" out.png
```

that convert the entire image to an alpha channel(both black and white are transparent)

```
ffmpeg -i image2colors.png -i background.png -filter_complex "[0]split[a][b];[a][b]alphamerge[c];[1][c]overlay[d]" -map [d] out.jpeg
```

this keeps the color white and made the black of the drawing transparent that, when overlayed, becomes red, also the color white is not so bright anymore, like it has a sort of transparency

this solved the question

```
ffmpeg -i image2colors.png -i background.png -filter_complex "[0]split[a][b];[a]negate[n];[b][n]alphamerge[c];[1][c]overlay[d]" -map [d] out.jpeg
```

that gave me a perfect black frame on alpha-channel overlayed to a colored background.(the jpeg shows that the overlay has gone correctly)
Seems that the alpha-merge chooses the black over the white.
i'm posting all of my mistakes because i made it by attempts and i still don't know what i'm doing.
if anyone has a more elegant way to obtain this result please answer to me with a lot of details.